# How to connecto to AWS Elasticsearch using mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am trying to create a search on my mongo db database. A good choice I thought was to use elasticsearch. So I started a cluster on aws elastic search. Beacuse I have this elasticsearch for development purposes I have set the access  policy to have open access to the domain.

```
this.es_connection = new elasticsearch.Client("elastic search end point as given on aws es domain page");

this.es_connection.ping(
 {
   requestTimeout: 30000,
   hello: 'elasticsearch'
 }, 
 function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!' + JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
    logger.info('All is well in elasticsearch');
  }
 }
);
```

to check I am trying to ping usgin elascticsearch package on npm.I am getting no living connection. The node server is running on local host.When I vising the end point url from my own browser I get the success message.

How do I use the aws es service with mongoosastic, I keep getting no living connection error. If AWS/ES is a rest api how can I use it with mongoosastic.

Comment: which port are you specifying? The REST endpoint is open at 443/80 ports.

Comment: I am using the https link in the endpoint given in the console. https should use 443 directly I thought.

Comment: Hi Piyush, issue is resolved? or you are still facing the issue while connecting to AWS ES

Comment: I opted for connect-mongo put the connector in my replica set, this option was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify your AWS credentials during connection. I'd recommend using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-aws-es. 
This worked for me:

```
var client = require('elasticsearch').Client({
  hosts: 'Your host',
  connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
  amazonES: {
    region: 'region',
    accessKey: 'key',
    secretKey: 'secretKey'
  }
});
```

Then also make sure you make proper queries, otherwise it will result in 400 error.